# ADD operation in assembly

Tags: variables, assembly, addition, x86-16, emu8086

It's been a while since I stopped working with some code languages and since a few days ago at school I began with assembly, I want to start understanding some logic behind the working of some lines of code.
Actually, what I tried is a simple ADD operation between two variables. I use emu8086 to emulate my code and I'll show you now why I can't understand it.

The code is the following:

```
stack segment
  dw 128 dup(0)
ends

data segment

  x DB 3
  y DB 5
  r DB 0

ends

code segment

   mov ah,x  
   mov al,y
   add ah,al
   mov r,ah   

ends
```

Now, I just initialized three variables, two of them on 8-bit and I want to add the first to the second.

The problem is the following: when I emulate the code and I go to see what happens step by step, the first step should be `AH=03`, but it seems to output CDh (and that is not my x var) and I can't get why. Same thing for `AL`.

I mean, why do I get other things written in my `AH` and `AL` registers instead of the x and y var?

Comment: You probably forgot to set up `DS` to point to your data segment.

Comment: Sorry for asking, but, how do I do that?

Answer (score 4):

All of your `mov` instructions address variables in memory referenced by the `DS` segment register. You need to set it up beforehand! Just add these few lines:

```
code segment
    mov ax, @data    <- Add this
    mov ds, ax       <- Add this
    mov ah, x  
    mov al, y
    add ah, al
    mov r, ah   
ends
```